# Custom tabs widget don't work in google chrome, is blocked, do not change the tabs. Why?

Tags: widgets, customization, jquery, sidebar, tabs

Code is the problem or is a Google Chrome issue?

**Here is the code:**

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Create the widget
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action('widgets_init', 'bd_post_types_init');

function bd_post_types_init(){

    register_widget('bd_post_types_widget');

}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Widget class
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
class bd_post_types_widget extends WP_Widget {


    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Widget Setup
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function bd_post_types_widget(){

        // Widget settings
        $ops = array('classname' => 'post-types-widget', 'description' => __('Display any post type: recent or popular, as text link or thumbnail', THEME_NAME) );

        // Create the widget
        $this->WP_Widget('post-types-widget', 'Post Types (All in one)', $ops);

    }

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Display Widget
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function widget($args, $instance){

        extract($args);

        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
        $count = $instance['count'];

        echo $before_widget;
        if (!empty($title)) echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        bd_post_types_widget($count, $instance['post-type'], $instance['type'], $instance['display'], $instance['category']);
        echo $after_widget;

    }

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Update Widget
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance){
        $instance = $old_instance;

        $instance['title'] = $new_instance['title'];
        $instance['count'] = $new_instance['count'];
        $instance['type'] = $new_instance['type'];
        $instance['post-type'] = $new_instance['post-type'];
        $instance['display'] = $new_instance['display'];
        $instance['category'] = $new_instance['category'];

        return $instance;
    }

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Displays the widget settings controls on the widget panel
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function form($instance){
        global $BD_theme;
            // Set up some default widget settings
            $defaults = array('title' => 'Recent Post', 'post-type' => '', 'count' =>'5', 'type' => 'thumbnail', 'display' => 'recent', 'category' => 'all');
            $instance = wp_parse_args((array) $instance, $defaults);

            $post_types = '';
            if(isset($BD_theme->options['post-types']) && is_array($BD_theme->options['post-types']))
                $post_types = $BD_theme->options['post-types'];

        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title', THEME_NAME); ?>:</label>
            <input class="widefat" type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>">
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('post-type'); ?>"><?php _e('Post Type', THEME_NAME ); ?>:</label><br>
            <select class="bd-cat-select" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('post-type'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('post-type'); ?>">
                <option value="post" <?php if($instance['post-type']=='post') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Post</option>
            <?php foreach($post_types as $k => $v): 
                $name = $k;     

                if(isset($v['name']))
                    $name = $v['name'].'s';

                if(isset($v['menu-name']))
                    $name = $v['menu-name'];
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $k; ?>" <?php if($instance['post-type']==$k) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $name; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach ; ?>

            </select>
        </p>
        <p id="bd-blog-categories">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('category'); ?>"><?php _e('Post Category (if post is selected)', THEME_NAME ); ?>:</label><br>
            <select  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('category'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('category'); ?>">
                <?php 
                $bd_categories = get_categories();
                $bd_categories_tab = array();
                foreach($bd_categories as $category){
                    $bd_categories_tab['all'] = 'All';
                    $bd_categories_tab[$category->cat_ID] = $category->name;
                } 

                foreach($bd_categories_tab as $k => $v):?>

                <option value="<?php echo $k; ?>" <?php if($instance['category']==$k) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $v; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>


            </select>
            <?php //debug($bd_categories_tab); ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('display'); ?>"><?php _e('Display', THEME_NAME ); ?>:</label><br>
            <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('display'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('display'); ?>">
                <option <?php if($instance['display']=='recent') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php _e('recent', THEME_NAME ); ?></option>
                <option <?php if($instance['display']=='featured') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php _e('featured', THEME_NAME ); ?></option>
                <option <?php if($instance['display']=='popular') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php _e('popular', THEME_NAME ); ?></option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('count'); ?>"><?php _e('Number of post', THEME_NAME ); ?>:</label>
            <input class="widefat" type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('count'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('count'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['count']; ?>">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('type'); ?>"><?php _e('Type' ,THEME_NAME ); ?>:</label>
            <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('type'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('type'); ?>">
                <option <?php if($instance['type']=='thumbnail') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php _e('thumbnail', THEME_NAME ); ?></option>
                <option <?php if($instance['type']=='text') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php _e('text', THEME_NAME ); ?></option>
                <?php if($BD_theme->options['video'] != array()): ?>
                <option <?php if($instance['type']=='video') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="video"><?php _e('video (only for video post types)', THEME_NAME ); ?></option>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </select>
        </p>
        <?php
    }



}

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Function
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function bd_post_types_widget($count=5, $post_type, $type, $display, $category){
        global $wpdb, $BD_theme, $post, $bd_ID;
        $do_not_duplicate = array();
        if(is_single())
            //echo $bd_ID;
            $do_not_duplicate[] = $bd_ID;

        $is_video = (in_array($post_type, $BD_theme->options['video'])) && ($post_type!='post');

        //$do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;
        if($type!='text'){
            if($display=='recent'){
                $args = array( 
                    'post_type' => array($post_type) ,
                    'posts_per_page' => $count,
                    'meta_key'    => '_thumbnail_id',
                    'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate
                    );

            }elseif($display=='featured'){
                $args = array( 
                'post_type' => array($post_type) ,
                'orderby' => 'post_date',
                'meta_key'    => '_thumbnail_id',
                'posts_per_page' => $count,
                'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate,
                'meta_query' => array(
                                         array(
                                              'key'     => 'bd_featured',
                                              'value'   => 'on',
                                              'compare' => '='
                                              )
                                         )
                );

            }elseif($display=='popular'){

                $args = array( 
                'post_type' => array($post_type) ,
                'orderby' => 'comment_count',
                'meta_key'    => '_thumbnail_id',
                'order'    => 'DESC',
                'posts_per_page' => $count,
                'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate,
                );
            }
        }else{

            if($display=='recent'){
                $args = array( 
                    'post_type' => array($post_type) ,
                    'posts_per_page' => $count,
                    'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate

                    );

            }elseif($display=='featured'){
                $args = array( 
                'post_type' => array($post_type) ,
                'orderby' => 'post_date',
                'posts_per_page' => $count,
                'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate,
                'meta_query' => array(
                                         array(
                                              'key'     => 'bd_featured',
                                              'value'   => 'on',
                                              'compare' => '='
                                              )
                                         )
                );

            }elseif($display=='popular'){

                $args = array( 
                'post_type' => array($post_type) ,
                'orderby' => 'comment_count',
                'order'    => 'DESC',
                'posts_per_page' => $count,
                'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate,
                );
            }

        }

        if($post_type == 'post' && $category!='all'){
            $args['category__in'] = $category;
        }

        $loop = new WP_Query($args);
        if ( $type=='text'){
            echo "<ul class=\"square\">";
        }elseif ( $type=='thumbnail' || $type=='video'){
            echo '<div class="widget-thumbnails-list">';
        }
        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        ?>
        <?php if ( $type=='video'): ?>
            <?php if($is_video): ?>
                <article>
                    <div class="frame" style="margin-top:15px; margin-bottom:5px">
                        <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_format_video_embed', true); ?>
                    </div>
                    <strong class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php _e('Permanent Link to', THEME_NAME); ?> <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></strong>
                                <br>
                    <small class="smooth"><?php echo get_the_time('F d, 20y'); ?></small>
                </article>

            <?php else: ?>
                <article>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="widget-thumb-link">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('mini', array('class' => 'frame', 'title' => "")); ?>
                    </a>
                    <strong class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php _e('Permanent Link to', THEME_NAME); ?> <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></strong><br>
                    <small class="smooth"><?php echo get_the_time('F d, 20y'); ?></small><br>
                    <small class="smooth"><?php bd_comment_number(); ?></small>
                    <?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bd_rating', true)!=''): ?>
                    <br>
                    <span class="small-star-<?php echo str_replace('.5', '-5', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bd_rating', true)); ?>"></span>
                    <?php endif; ?> 
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </article>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php elseif ( ($type=='thumbnail') ): ?>
                <?php if($is_video): ?>
                    <article>
                        <div class="video-thumbnail">
                            <a class="video-thumbnail-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('video-thumbnail-img', array('class' => '')); ?>
                                <span class="play-button-thumb"></span>
                            </a>
                            <strong class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php _e('Permanent Link to', THEME_NAME); ?> <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></strong>
                            <br>
                            <small class="smooth"><?php echo get_the_time('F d, 20y'); ?></small><br>
                            <small class="smooth"><?php bd_comment_number(); ?></small>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                <?php else: ?>
                    <article>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="widget-thumb-link">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('mini', array('class' => 'frame effect', 'title' => "")); ?>
                        </a>
                        <strong class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php _e('Permanent Link to', THEME_NAME); ?> <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></strong>
                            <br>
                        <small class="smooth"><?php echo get_the_time('F d, 20y'); ?></small><br>
                        <small class="smooth"><?php bd_comment_number(); ?></small>

                        <?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bd_rating', true)!=''): ?>
                        <br>
                        <span class="small-star-<?php echo str_replace('.5', '-5', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bd_rating', true)); ?>"></span>
                        <?php endif; ?> 
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </article>

            <?php endif; ?> 
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <?php else: // if text ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="hover">
                    <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?> 
        <?php
        endwhile;
        if ( $type=='text'){
            echo "</ul>";
        }else{
            echo '</div>';
        }
        ?><div class="clear"></div><?php
    }
```

Comment: Blocked?  As in the widget doesn't appear at all?  

Are any errors or warnings shown in the Chrome console?

Comment: The widget appears, but when I click the tabs (3 tabs: recent, popular, comments), nothing happen. Is locked on first tab. Only In Google Chrome. Works in Firefox and IE.

Comment: Sounds like a jQuery issue then, can you link to that code?

Also check the Chrome development console.  It may give you the fastest answer.

Comment: Here is the link for jQuery code: https://code.google.com/p/socr/source/browse/trunk/SOCR_3.0/SOCR_HTML5_MotionCharts/jquery-ui-1.8.20/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js?r=205

Comment: [Chrome Developer Tools : Console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I find the problem**. The issues are caused by **Internet Download Manager** extension.
When is disable, the tabs works.

**Is there a way to fix this compatibility?**